# how to use gl_InstanceID in ANGLE_instanced_arrays?

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0

WebGL 1 only supports GLSL **ES** [v1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf). Instanced draw calls are supported with the
 [ANGLE_instanced_arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ANGLE/ANGLE_instanced_arrays.txt) extension.

The extension was so popular that it became part of WebGL 2.0 [DrawArraysInstance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/drawArraysInstanced).
WebGL 2.0 has support for higher versions of GLSL that support built-in `gl_InstanceID` and `gl_VertexID`.

However since WebGL 1 is stuck at the old GLSL version, those variables are not supported.
But they can be simulated, or i hope they can!

To simulate `gl_VertexID` i simply use an Array Buffer of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`,
and bind it with a Divisor of `0`, This works well.

However, i have no idea how to simulate `gl_InstanceID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i figured it out! I can have another attribute bound to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` Array Buffer, with Divisor of `1`.

That attribute will increment once per instance, same as `gl_InstanceID`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. There is no `gl_InstanceID` in WebGL1 so you have to emulate it with your own attribute