# Is GL_EXT_draw_instanced supported in WebGL1

Tags: webgl, webgl-extensions

I want to add instancing to my WebGL application, which works fine using `gl_InstanceID` for devices running WebGL2. However, I want to also support older devices running WebGL1 - apparently this is available as an extension for OpenGLES2.0 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041936/use-of-undeclared-identifier-gl-instanceid/28043341#28043341)):

```
#extension GL_EXT_draw_instanced : enable
#define gl_InstanceID gl_InstanceIDEXT
```

However, it doesn't look like WebGL1 supports this extension (at least not on the devices I've tested with). Is the list at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Using_Extensions) the canonical list? Is there another way to support instancing for WebGL? I found [this thread](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/public_webgl/1003/msg00047.php) that has someone offering an implementation, but unfortunately the links are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official canonical list for WebGL extensions can be found here:
https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/extensions/

WebGL1 does support instancing through the [`ANGLE_instanced_arrays`](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/extensions/ANGLE_instanced_arrays/) extension ([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ANGLE_instanced_arrays)). It has the same functionality and API(postfixed with `ANGLE`) as the WebGL2 default functionality, **however** GLSL ES 1.0 does *not* support `gl_InstanceID` so you'll have to implement a [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690863/how-to-use-gl-instanceid-in-angle-instanced-arrays) if you require it.